# Behavior react-native linking

Tags: react-native, react-native-deep-linking

My question is about Linking of react-native : https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

I implement this functionnality but I have a behavior that I don't want.

In case of my app is close, I click on a link and my app start. But before the link is detected my app start normaly, and after the link detected by the method `Linking.getInitialURL()` the redirection is done.
I find this behavior weird because the application starts as if it had been started normally and after a delay the link is detected and the redirection is executed. The user see the start useless screen before the redirecton.

**Moroever it's a problem if the redirection with url is faster than the normally redirection. We see firt the redirection with url, and after the redirection of open app. So user can't access to the link redirection.**

I don't know how resolve properly this problem.

[image]

Comment: What about showing the user URL and redirect him onPress? if i understand correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. But I don't think is user friendly.

Comment: I added a picture to help understand my problem.
One solution is to put a timeout to wait the redirection A, so that the redirection A is done before B, but the Loading context can take an indefinite time.
I'm not a fan of this solution.

Comment: this question is hard to understand. can u add a step by step example of wrong behavior? e.g. open page A, redirection url of page B is displaying ...